# Django 1.4: how to use documentation

Tags: django

I'm a newbie. In my textbook there is this example:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db import models

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 150)
    body = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()

class BlogPostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'timestamp')

admin.site.register(BlogPost, BlogPostAdmin)
```

When I started playing with it, I discovered that I may use both tuples and lists here (either list_display = ('title', 'timestamp') or list_display = ['title', 'timestamp']).

Could you help me find in the documentation the answer to the question why this is possible?
That may help me elaborate some skills in working with the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I shouldn't think it would be mentioned in the Django documentation. It's trivial Python: in most cases, lists and tuples are equivalent, because the code is just expecting an iterable, which both of those are.

That's probably the point you're missing - it's to do with duck typing, where as long as the object exposes the expected functionality (iterable in this case), you shouldn't care what exact type it is.

Answer (score 0):

In places where you only read the sequence, a list is equivalent to a tuple. Compare `dir([])` to `dir(())` and find out that they have lot in common but the tuple is missing everything that can change it. http://ideone.com/iHd0h

Answer (score 0):

I think that code works because the index accessor used is the same in Python for both tuple and list. This is not specific for Django, it works on all Python code.

```
# a is a list
a = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
# while b is a tuple
b = ('b1', 'b2', 'b3',)
c = a
print(c[1])
c= b
print(c[1])
```

It will print:

```
a2
b2
```

This is called [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

*When I see a bird that walks like a duck and swims like a duck and quacks like a duck, I call that bird a duck.*